# What is causing this issue for my vertices to not move?

Tags: edit-mode, vertices

I do not know what caused this, but I found a way to fix it was by adding loop cuts on the sides and then dissolving the loop that is not moving then adding the loop cut to replace it. I am unable to find answers for this on Google, so I resorted to asking here.

If there is a better way to fix this, let me know!

I tried merging by distance, with no changes (none were merged).

[image: GIF of vertices not moving]

Comment: Do you have snapping enabled? Do you have modifiers on the object?

Comment: i am sorry, but we have no idea what you did and you didn't show us any settings you have made. so pls provide blend file so we can check it out. thx.

Comment: You will have to give us some context here, to give us a clue. This is proportional editing? Are there any other influences on the mesh? Best to share your file on https://blend-exchange.com/ .

Comment: You have proportional editing enabled, see the white circle when you move your verts. Press "O". Or you have a mirror modifier enabled with "Clipping" option

Comment: Yes, I had proportional on because I needed to use it for editing. I did not have snapping on. This only happens when I move the mesh in edit mode USING proportional to keep the mesh SYMMETRICAL that I was editing. Since I fixed this error, I do not have the faulty mesh still. This happens when I also import other creator's meshes and the vertices that SHOULD move don't (usually 3-4 verts on the other side). I just wanted to know what could be CAUSING the vertices to not move with a mesh I didn't even rig or weight paint yet!